# make css item stick to the right of the srcoll

Tags: html, css

I would like the check boxes stick to right.

This is how i want to be:

[image]

When i use  `right: 0; position: absolute !important;`

**It sticks always to right even i scroll right and this is how it should be.**

My issue: even if scroll down - chechboxes also scroll down with the scroll,
But i want them to stick to the label and now scroll down with the scroll but
to be the same like in pic 1.
How can i do it ?

[image]

This is my CSS

```
.custom-tree-node {
  // flex: 1;
  // display: flex;
  // width: 90%;

  & > .custom-tree-node-buttons {
    right: 0;
    position: absolute !important;
  }

  & > .custom-tree-node-buttons {
    & > .el-button-group {
      & > .el-button {
        padding: 2px 3px !important;
      }
    }
  }

  & > .custom-tree-node-label {
    flex: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: pre;
    position: relative;
  }
```

HTML:

```
                 <Tree v-if="allStructuresTree.length > 0"
      style="padding:0px;width: 100%;display: flex;"
      class="custom-tree-node"
        filterMode="strict"
        :value="levelDetils"
        :loading="loadingPrime"
        ref="structureTree"
        selectionMode="multiple"
        v-model:selectionKeys="selectedKeys"
        @nodeSelect="onCurrentNodeChanged"
        :expandedKeys="expandedKeys"
         @nodeExpand="onNodeExpand" 
         @nodeUnselect="onNodeUnselect"
      >
        <template #default="slotProps" style="padding:0px">
            <div draggable="true" @dragstart="onDragging" id="123"
             
              v-bind:class="
                getStructureLabelClass(
                  slotProps.node.item.isHighlighted,
                  slotProps.node.item.isUnderlined
                )
              "
              :title="slotProps.node.item.name"
            >
              <i
                v-if="
                  slotProps.node.item.linkedTasks != null &&
                  slotProps.node.item.linkedTasks.length != 0
                "
                class="el-icon-fa-link"
                v-on:click="showLinkedTask(slotProps.node.item.linkedTasks[0])"
              ></i>
              <span
                class="xeokit-context-menu-item noselect"
                @mousedown.right="mousedown($event, slotProps.node)"
                v-on:dblclick="doubleClick($event, slotProps.node)"
                @contextmenu.prevent
                >{{ slotProps.node.item.name }}</span
              >
            </div>
            <div class="custom-tree-node-buttons" v-if="isSceneLoaded">
              <el-button-group
                class="treeBtns"
                v-if="slotProps.node.item.visible"
              >
                <el-button style="padding:0px 5px; margin-right: 5px;"
                  @click="
                    focusOnItem(
                      $event,
                      slotProps.node.item.idOnScene,
                      slotProps.node
                    )
                  "
                >
                  <i class="el-icon-fa-dot-circle-o"></i>
                </el-button>
                <el-button style="padding:0px 5px;">
                  <input
                    @click="toggleShowItem($event, slotProps.node)"
                    type="checkbox"
                    v-show="slotProps.node.item.entity"
                    v-bind:id="slotProps.node.objectId"
                    v-model="slotProps.node.item.entity.checked"
                  />
                </el-button>
              </el-button-group>
            </div>
        </template>
      </Tree>

}
```

Comment: It looks like you're using Vuej.js. Please add the minimal code to reproduce the issue in question. See [mcve]

Comment: This is more about css then vue js

Comment: We can't do much without the HTML structure to reproduce the image

Comment: I have edited the code, Now you can see all the relevant code.

Comment: What is `Tree`, `<el-button>` etc? Please actually read [mcve]. It's stackoverflow guidelines, I didn't write this.

Comment: https://element-plus.org/ and https://www.primefaces.org/primevue/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

position: sticky
have solved my issue.